# Wait X block confirmations ethers contract deployment

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

Right now, I can deploy a contract with `ethers` and `hardhat` like so:

```
const SimpleStorageFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("SimpleStorage")
const simpleStorage = await SimpleStorageFactory.deploy()
await simpleStorage.deployed()
```

However, our contract isn't guaranteed to be deployed. Is there a way to wait x block confirmations off a contract?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## 2023 Update

The `contract` object comes with a `deploymentTransaction` attribute, that has all the same attributes and functions a normal object has, so you can just do:

```
await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction.wait(6)
```

To wait 6 blocks

## Previously

The `contract` object comes with a `deployTransaction` attribute, that has all the same attributes and functions a normal object has, so you can just do:

```
await simpleStorage.deployTransaction.wait(6)
```

To wait 6 blocks

Comment: Where does the number 6 came from?

Comment: I just picked 6. 6 is usually pretty good.

Comment: Hey @PatrickCollins, first of all, thank you for all content, its impressive!

I think now with ethers6 they changed and we don't have anymore the `.deployTransaction`:

`TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="deployTransaction", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.6.7)`

I passed it using the line below:
`await contract.deploymentTransaction().wait(6)`

:rocket

Comment: Are you using `hardhat-deploy`? I don't see that function in the ethers docs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that on recent versions of Hardhat, the `deployTransaction` attribute has been replaced in favor of a new function called `deploymentTransaction`. So you would need to do instead:

```
await simpleStorage.deploymentTransaction().wait(6);
```

(where 6 is the number of confirmations to wait)